# Combinatorics how many clock combinations of different 4 digits using 24 wise clock

Tags: combinatorics

I tried solving this problem and I got into a nice way, sadly I think I might be wrong.

What I thought of doing is separating (0/1)H:MM and 2H:MM from each other while calculating

While calculating (0/1)H:MM I came to this calculation: 2 * 9 * 4 * 7 = 588

2 - for two options

9 - for one less option (0 to 9) - 0/1

4 - The first M is between (0 - 5) - (0/1 + (0 to 9)) = 6 - 2

7 - What is left is calculating the last M which is has 10 options minus 3 options already written

The second calculation I got was 1 * 3 * 4 * 7

1 - I was calculating only for first M = 2 => only one option

3 - you have three options which can happen 20, 21, 23 (22 is same digit which is forbidden)

4 - you have two numbers down so form the 6 numbers available deduct 2 => 6-2 = 4

7 - You have already chosen 3 numbers and now you have 10 - 3 which is 7.

This is what I came up with, but I think it might be wrong because a friend's tested it on his computer and got 646.
the question is what did I do wrong and how can you truly calculate this correctly?

Comment: For the 0/1 case: Pick in the order  AC:BD.  That is, first pick the tens-digit of the hour.  *Then* pick the tens-digit of the minutes.  Only after that should you continue on to picking the units-digit of the hour and units-digit of the minutes.  The reason why you need to order it in this way is to make it consistent how many options you still have for the tens-digit of the minutes noting that if you did it from left-to-right only in certain situations would you have only 4 options remaining for tens-digit of minutes while other situations you still have 5 options remaining.

Comment: "*A friend tested it on his computer and got. 646..*" By my count I get $2\cdot 5\cdot 8\cdot 7 + 1\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 7 = 644$

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was mistaken he wrote 644 like you.
I understand your answer, thank you vary much! it makes more sense now.
I knew something was off about how the counting was.

Answer (score 1):

There are $24 - 3 = 21$ possibilities for the hour (00, 11 and 22 excluded). $10$ of these have 0 or 1 as 1st digit and 0 to 5 as 2nd digit and $3$ start with 2 (20, 21, 23); in these $13$ cases there are $4$ possibilities for the 1st digit of the minute and $7$ for the 2nd: $13 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 = 364$. The other $8$ cases for the hour have $5$ possibilities for the 1st digit of the minute and $7$ for the 2nd: $8 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 280$. The sum is $364 + 280 = 644$.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to understand, but a great calculation I like it.
Thank you very much!